# Symfony translation fatal error exception in catalogue

Tags: php, symfony

I've got this error on ubuntu srver 14.04 (on local works perfect on windows 8 with xampp), if have any suggestion please help.

```
FATALERROREXCEPTION: ERROR: CALL TO UNDEFINED METHOD  SIMPLEXMLELEMENT::__SET_STATE()
IN /VAR/WWW/xxx/APP/CACHE/DEV/TRANSLATIONS/CATALOGUE.FR.74AD548A14679603165A68A05F1F6A84F1AB7740.PHP LINE 9
```

note : I cleared the cache and gived permissions to the cache and logs folders

```
chmod -R 777 app/cache 
chmod -R 777 app/logs
```

but the error doesn't go away.

ُEdit:

I compared the catalogue file generated on the local and the one on the server and I found that on the local the call to SimpleXMLElement::__set_state isn't used, why is this deference ?

on local server

```
'This value should be false.' => 'Cette valeur doit être fausse.',
```

on the server

```
SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(0 => 'Cette valeur doit être fausse.',)),
```

Edit 2:

I copied the content of the local catalogue file to the server file and it worked, but I need to understand and resolve normally not by hacking it.

Comment: What is the line CATALOGUE.FR.74AD548A14679603165A68A05F1F6A84F1AB7740.PHP LINE 9?

Comment: Here is the code in the line 9 : `SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(0 => 'Cette valeur doit être fausse.',)),`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to [this answer](https://www.drupal.org/node/215375) on another topic this could be an issue depending on your PHP version.

Do the versions differ between XAMPP and your Ubuntu installation?

Comment: When I can have this information I'll answer, you thank you

Comment: I verified the versions on the server 5.5.9 and on the local 5.5.11